# No limit shape for random Young diagrams under z-measure?

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, young-tableaux

In their paper *[Random partitions and the Gamma kernel](http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0305043)* (Advances in Mathematics 194 (2005) 141–202), Borodin and Olshanski state that:

> An important difference between the Plancherel measures and the z-measures is that the random Plancherel diagrams have a limit form... while no such form exists for the z-measures.

I am not sure if this is a straightforward comment (because the z-measure is in general not positive), or more subtle. That is, **is there still no limit shape for those values where the z-measure is positive?**. If not, why?

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is contained in a more careful reading of the paper above.

If one is interested in the point process describing the *largest* Frobenius coordinates of the partition in the limit of large partitions, one has to scale the coordinates by a parameter proportional to the size (it corresponds to the $(1-\xi)$, where $\xi$, is the parameter defining the negative binomial distribution.

On the other hand, the point process describing the *smallest* Frobenius coordinates requires no such scaling. The implication is then that one expects to young diagram to become ever more elongated (a thinner L shape) as the size increases.